# What does "IsTransactional" in NServiceBus mean?

Tags: transactions, nservicebus

I am creating a web application that is going to *send* messages using NServiceBus, and also write to a database. I want this to be an atomic operation, i.e. a transaction, so I wrap the code in a using new TransactionScope() statement.

When configuring NServiceBus you can call the IsTransactional-method. When do I pass 'false' to this method, and when is 'true' appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IsTransactional(true) mean that all **incoming** messages will be processed within a transactionscope

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/architecture/
http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/architecture/principles

For sends (outgoing messages) you need to create your own transaction scope to make sure that you're consitent with your database. Usually it's a good idea to move the actual processing (like writing to the database) to backend processes. If you do that NServiceBus will handle things like retries, exception management etc for you.

More about that here:

http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/10/why-not-publish-nservicebus-messages-from-a-web-application/

Comment: Just to clarify: We are receiving large binary attachments, possibly exceeding 2MB, in a web service. So we store the data temporarily in a database, and send the Id in a message. Something akin to the [Claim Check pattern](http://www.eaipatterns.com/StoreInLibrary.html)

Comment: yes that sounds like a good design, just fyi NServiceBus 3.0 will have a "databus" feature that does that for you out of the box. I don't see the need to have the writing to the db and the bus.send to be in the same tx so you could suppress any transaction to get better performance