# How do I configure distributed transactions for NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

I have the following scenario.

1. First write something to a db
2. Send message on bus

I want to execute those like an atomic action, that is, running them in a transaction but can't get it to work when it is really distributed. Everything was working fint on local machine, but as soon as the service was on another machine it stopped working.

My code looks something like this:

```
using(var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Write something to db
    _bus.Send(SomeMessage);
    ts.Complete();
}
```

I have done everything I could think of and find information about, like enabling DTC on client, server and db with inbound and outbound enabled, set the port DCOM protocols to 5000-6000. The error I get is:

```
 FailedToSendMessageException: "Failed to send message to address: myserver"
```

and the stacktrace is:

```
at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.ThrowFailedToSendException(Address address, Exception ex) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqMessageSender.cs:line 89
at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqMessageSender.cs:line 80
at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(List`1 addresses, String correlationId, MessageIntentEnum messageIntent, Object[] messages) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 658
at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(Address address, String correlationId, MessageIntentEnum messageIntent, Object[] messages) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 583
at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IBus.Send(Object[] messages) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 480
at Rapporteringsregisteret.Web.Controllers.RapporteringController.Post(OpprettRapportering opprettRapportering) in c:\dev\git\Rapporteringsregisteret\src\Rapporteringsregisteret.Web\Controllers\RapporteringController.cs:line 37
at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Your DB transaction and the .Send() should automatically enlist in the ambient transaction.  Have you tried it without the TransactionScope?

Comment: I have removed the `TransactionScope`, but then if something goes wrong with the send for some reason the db would still be comitted. As of now I just removed the transaction as you said since the likelyhood that send will go wrong is so small, but I would really like to know how it should be done.

Comment: Did you configure the Bus to be transactional or not?  If it is, I'm wondering if we have some competition.

Comment: @AdamFyles, I'll try that when I get to work tomorrow. I haven't explicitly set `IsTransactional(true)`, so that depends on what the default is.

Comment: @AdamFyles, apparently I already had enabled transactions with: `            NServiceBus.Configure.Transactions.Enable()` as one should since v4.

Comment: Can you include your full configuration?  Also you may want to consider moving that processing to the background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168673/what-does-istransactional-in-nservicebus-mean

Comment: We used DTC ping to troubleshoot our DTC setup. You need to be able to ping from nservicebus server to db server. Mabye that will help you http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2868

Answer (score 1):

When running in a distributed scenario your endpoint mapping needs to explicitely define the machine name where the queue of the receiver is located. When running on the same box this is not necessary. Therefore your mapping should not contain "myserver" but "myserver@machinename". This error is not related to DTC. For future questions always include Nservicebus version number and transport layer

Comment: That's not the problem, the config has "myserver@machinename", I just simplified the message. I wonder if the problem is there because I'm running the client as a asp.net application and it is on the client I want to do the logic described.

Comment: Does your code have the access security for that queue? You need to setup the rights for the IIS process to access that queue

Comment: Yes, everything works if I don't have the surrounding transaction.